# Rails: Whitelisting nested parameters / Permitted Parameters / Nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, nested-forms

I've been tinkering with the Rails 5.0 permit function for quite some time now, but I just can't get it right and really need some help:

I have this white listing function. And when executed I get the following response:

> Unpermitted parameter: studio_users_attributes

I have this white listing function

```
def studio_params
  params.require(:studio).permit(:name, :name_long, :address, :address2,
                                 :zip, :city, :country, :phone,
                                 :entity_id, { studio_users_attributes: [] } ) 
end
```

The params method returns me following:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"VZTPSpsmNJxcqc[...]", 
 "studio"=>{"studio_users_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"viewing_rights"=>"Nur eigene", 
 "id"=>"4"}, "1"=>{"viewing_rights"=>"Alle", "id"=>"5"}}}, 
 "commit"=>"Studio aktualisieren", "controller"=>"studios",
 "action"=>"update", "id"=>"2"
}
```

Some help would be highly appreciated.

Philipp

Comment: Can you please update the question with relevant model code and form code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more experimenting I managed to solve it.

For the nested parameters I had to explicitly add the keys to the nested-hash:

```
def studio_params
params.require(:studio).permit(:name, :name_long, :address, :address2, :zip, 
                               :city, :country, :phone, :entity_id, 
                                studio_users_attributes: [:id, :viewing_rights] )
```

Leaving the hash empty (studio_users_attributes: []), would still result in

> "Unpermitted parameter: studio_users_attributes  "

Answer (score 0):

In the controller you use `studio_users_params`.

But you send `studio_users_attributes`.

Comment: Hi Danil, thx for your first, reply. This happened to be an error on my side. I corrected it, unfortunately still doesn't work. I still think, the error is from not having properly white-listed the nested parameters.

Comment: No, still the same

Comment: No, doesn't change anything. Same response: "Unpermitted parameter: studio_users_attributes"